# I can't set Key restrictions HTTP referrers (websites) to my domain

Tags: firebase-authentication

**Strange thing when in Firebase apis key restriction I set like this:**

Image:

[image]

**For my website:
https://greta.portplays.com/**

**I then get this error when linking accounts:**

Image:

[image]

But if I remove https://greta.portplays.com/ from Key restrictions HTTP referrers (websites) to my domain, it work ok!

And as the error message say "Add your domain (greta.portplays.com) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab"

I have also done that look:

Image:

[image]

So when I add a key restriction it breaks by saying I have not added a OAuth redirect domain even I have and that works, what does the first have to do with later?

Is there so that I can't use both  Sign-in method's Authorised domains and the apis restriction?

The same thing happened in another Firebase App where I set Key restrictions HTTP referrers (websites) to "localhost".

It's like I can't use the Key restrictions at all! I have restarted laptop, turned of VPN but still can't log in user by linking the anonymous account.

[image]